# Spring Data Test - two identical objects as set return two another hashcode

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit

I try to test my Spring Repository by @DataJpaTest.
I want to found exactly this same user by email, but I get another set for roles.

Firstly If I start my project then I setup test user and roles to him.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SetupDataLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
private final UserService userService;
boolean alreadySetup = false;

@Override
@Transactional
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

    if (alreadySetup)
        return;

    createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_USER");
    createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_ADMIN");

    if (userRepository.findByUsername("test123") == null) {
        UserRegistrationDto user = new UserRegistrationDto();
        user.setUsername("test123");
        user.setPassword("Test12345");
        user.setEmail("test@test.com");
        userService.save(user);
    }

    alreadySetup = true;
}

@Transactional
Role createRoleIfNotFound(String name) {

    Role role = roleRepository.findByName(name);
    if (role == null) {
        role = roleRepository.save(new Role(name));
    }
    return role;
}
```

Piece of code from UserService where user will be saved.

```
public void save(UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto) {
    userValidator.userRegistrationValidator(userRegistrationDto);

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(userRegistrationDto.getUsername());
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userRegistrationDto.getPassword()));
    user.setEmail(userRegistrationDto.getEmail());
    user.setEnabled(true);
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER"));
    user.setRoles(roles);

    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

So next step is my repository test. I want to find user by email.

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class UserRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private UserRepository testUserRepository;

@Autowired
private RoleRepository testRoleRepository;

@Test
void shouldFindUserByEmail() {
    //given
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(testRoleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER"));

    User user = new User();
    user.setId(1L);
    user.setUsername("test123");
    user.setPassword("$2a$10$Dk0CTgpWyqckt/UmSviLmOOYeqWpf4lFeuZcoLvW33LdZqRAYI2lW");
    user.setEmail("test@test.com");
    user.setRoles(roles);
    user.setEnabled(true);

    //when
    User userWithMail = testUserRepository.findByEmail("test@test.com");
    //then
    assertThat(userWithMail).isEqualTo(user);
}
```

Here Is debug from this method

[image]

I got two different roles one as HashSet from test method and second PersistentSet from database, so these objects are different. Why I got PersistentSet? Is it because of database did anything? Can someone explain whats this PersistentSet exist? One more clue, roles are many to many with user model.

Is good idea to compare objects in tests or for example username/email is enough?

Answer (score 0):

> assertThat(userWithMail).isEqualTo(user);

Did you override equals() method in User? Otherwise Java defaults to comparing a reference - in which case two separate objects will always be different (`new User().equals(new User())` would return false).

If you don't want to override equals() yourself, in your test you could look for a method that does field by field comparison - AssertJ has for instance `isEqualToComparingFieldByField()`, which should return true.

It should return true by the way, because Sets define equals() method in a way that ensures any Set implementation with the exact same content will be equal to one another. So it won't matter that Hibernate uses a wrapper implementation, and that PersistentSet will be equal to your HashSet if all the elements match. Well, that's if the elements do match - which might require overriding equals() and hashCode() of Role entity.

Comment: Yes, I did override equals and hashcode by Intellij mechanism(Role and User model). isEqualToComparingFieldByField() Intellij mark it as deprecated but despite this I tried to test and test failed. The weird thing is this Set(model and test) contain Role with this same address, but Set is different.

Comment: It's just how Hibernate behaves, provides a wrapper for Set for internal purposes, ry toso that's what you get when you pull from FB. And, if comparison field by field fails try to narrow down which fields exactly are failing. If it's the Set comparison, maybe equals/hashcode implementation is wrong?